# Spree_static_content gem not working with spree 3.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Have to create static pages using the same layout of rest of the spree commerce site. Spree_static_content is the gem I tried using. However, getting following error on bundle install.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    spree_core (= 3.3.1)

  In Gemfile:
    spree (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.3.1)

    spree (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.3.1)

    spree (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.3.1)

    spree (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.3.1)

    spree (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.3.1)

    spree_gateway (~> 3.3) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      spree_core (< 4.0, >= 3.1.0)

    spree_gateway (~> 3.3) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      spree_core (< 4.0, >= 3.1.0)

    spree_static_content was resolved to 3.0.1, which depends on
      spree_core (~> 3.0.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution this issue is because of dependent gem globalize with Rails 5. Add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'globalize', git: 'https://github.com/globalize/globalize'
gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml'
```

Next, `bundle install` and you will net the above-mentioned error in questions.