# Spree static content gem setup throwing error with Spree 3.X and rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, spree

After adding the gem to the Gemfile, `bundle install` and `bundle exec rails g spree_static_content:install`. Migrations are getting failed and getting following error :

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant Spree::Page::SpreeGlobalize
```

Comment: Was this before or after installing the spree globalize gem here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47239544/2558108

Comment: After installing the Gem